# How can I increase the max number of concurrent connections in rails 4.2.0?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, connection-pooling, puma

I am using postgres and rails 4.2.0.
 
Production Server is Puma.
When I trigger multiple ActiveRecord queries in different threads, I get the following error: 
"could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.010 seconds)".

I saw the database.yml file and here are the configurations.

production:
   pool: 15

development:
   pool: 25

How do I know how many DB connections do I need at any point of time?

Whe I trigger the same query sequentially, it takes 0.00005 sec for one query. So, for 12 queries, it still takes less than 1 sec.

But If triggered simultaneously, it gives the error as mentioned above.

I referred the below heroku links
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections

Waiting for 5 seconds is too much.

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many Puma threads/workers are you using?

Comment: Web dyno: 1,
Worker dyno: 1,
RAILS_MAX_THREADS  = 1